# Do all IPv4 IP addresses have an IPv6 equivalent?

Tags: ipv6

Generally I want to know when and where to use IPv6 and also if it is necessarry for each server to support both or if they can support only IPv6.

Obviously we would need to make sure the ISP and routers are set up for IPv6 first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by 'equivalent' that the server sitting on ipv4 only can be reached from ipv6 network, it can: 192.0.2.128 is reached from ipv6 networks by visiting ::ffff:192.0.2.128

If you want to have the server sitting on ipv6 it's a bad idea like mrdenny says, but it's technically (and very awkwardly) possible with methods explained on http://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/ :
access the ipv6-only http://www.kame.net/ by appending .ipv4.sixxs.org to it = http://www.kame.net.ipv4.sixxs.org/

The turtle is dancing only on ipv6 connections :)

So yes it's possible to have the server on ipv6 only, but you would definately want to go for mrdennys solution.

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you want to support IPv6 today that would be in addition to support IPv4 otherwise you'll be leaving some people not able to reach you.

Comment: Oh well,, I am curious: Is it the same the other way around? Does an IPv6 client have to also support IPv4 to get to IPv4 servers?

Comment: No, they are totally separate IP schemes.  For an IPv4 user to get to an IPv6 website the IPv4 users ISP would need to have an IPv4 to IPv6 NAT (PAT technically) system in place to translate the traffic between the two.  Same goes for IPv6 users trying to get to an IPv4 website.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey For a client you could go all IPv6 but you would also need a 6 to 4 translator. You pick an unused /96 from your site's IPv6 address range which will be used as the NAT64 prefix and all IPv4 addresses would be embedded in it. See TAYGA http://www.litech.org/tayga/ for a Linux implementation and  more generally http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanisms#NAT64